# Remove image from gallery on LongClick event

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm new in android, here i'm using `Gallery` to show images in my application, working fine but the problem is now I want show some option like remove images from gallery on the `LongClick` event of the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779023/android-remove-a-view-from-a-gallery) may help you.

Use code to set **onLongClickListener** on Gallery object

```
gal.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() 
{

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) 
    {
        // Remove element from array and call adapter.notifysetdatachanged() to update
        // Gallery

        return false;
    }
});
```